# Forwarding traffic through an OpenVPN tunnel

Tags: debian, openvpn, forwarding

I'm attempting to set up a Raspberry Pi (192.168.1.118) in such a way that it allows all traffic that uses it as the default gateway to be pushed through an external OpenVPN tunnel (Private Internet Access) using a single physical interface.

I've configured IP forwarding and it works as a gateway however when I start the OpenVPN tunnel no traffic can get leave the network unless it originates from the Raspberry Pi or the router, when I stop OpenVPN the traffic goes trough without a problem.

The output of `route` while running the VPN is:

```
default 10.104.1.5 128.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 tun0
default 192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eth0
10.104.1.1 10.104.1.5 255.255.255.255 UGH 0 0 0 tun0
10.104.1.5 * 255.255.255.255 UH 0 0 0 tun0
128.0.0.0 10.104.1.5 128.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 tun0
192.168.1.0 * 255.255.255.0 U 0 0  0 eth0
```

`iptables -L FORWARD -nv`: returns nothing and allows no traffic with NATing on the VPN network.

`tcpdump -i tun0 -n` shows failing DNS lookups.

Any help anyone could offer world be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `ip route` and `iptables -L FORWARD -nv` when OpenVPN is running? Does `tcpdump -i tun0 -n` show any traffic in the tunnel?